# How to print carriage return (\r) only on OSX

Tags: macos, bash

I have a script (it's php actually, but the concept is the same as bash) that prints a progress bar in the terminal.
I use carriage return \r to put the carriage back at the beginning of a line.

Unfortunately, printing \r on a OSX produces a newline.

Is there any other character or simple way around just moving the carriage on OSX in terminal?

Comment: I'm testing this bash command in Linux and OS X and I get the same result: `echo -e "--------\rtest"` which outputs `test----`, are you getting something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps use [ANSI escape characters](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) for cursor movement.

```
printf $'\033[s'
progress=0
print_progress() { printf "%#$(($1))s" " " | tr ' ' '#' ; }
while [ $progress -lt 100 ]; do 
    print_progress $progress
    printf $'\033[u'
    sleep 0.1
    ((progress++))
done
echo
```

Comment: I've just come across that as a possible solution. I've tested echo "\033[100D"; on Linux, but I don't know if that will work on OSX.

Comment: ANSI code `\e[100D` will move the cursor 100 columns to left. But there is a catch: if you are currently at column number > 100, you will not be at 1st column after the movement.

Comment: I've actually ended up with `printf $'\033[0G'` which moves the cursor to column n

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of all the options for tput on OSX but this may work

#### Example

```
while [[ x -lt 100 ]];do
   ((x+=10))
   tput sc
   echo -n $x%
   sleep 1
   tput el1
   tput rc
done
```

#### Explanation

```
tput sc
```

Save the cursor position

```
tput el1
```

Clears line to the left

```
tput rc
```

Returns cursor position