# printing backslash r (\r) in g++ does not work at mac terminal

Tags: c++, g++, cout, carriage-return

I have a function to print \r (carriage return escape character) to overwrite the previously printed chars as shown below.

```
// show the current time in military form.
void show(Clock *ptr)  {
    cout.fill('0');
    cout << setw(2) << ptr->hr << ":"
         << setw(2) << ptr->min << ":"
         << setw(2) << ptr->sec << "\r";
}
```

It works as expected in PC Windows (PS/Cmd console), but not in Mac terminal. Is there a way to make it work in a mac terminal?
(a debtor)<><

Comment: Have you tried with `printf("\r")` instead of `cout`?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769973/how-to-print-carriage-return-r-only-on-osx